# Enabled plugin does not want to show, why I am missing here?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to enable a plugin in CKEditor 4.0.x which code looks like the one below:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('strinsert', {
    requires: ['richcombo'],
    init: function (editor) {
        //  array of strings to choose from that'll be inserted into the editor
        var strings = [];

        strings.push(['%faq%', 'FAQs', 'FAQs']);
        strings.push(['%glossary%', 'Glossary', 'Glossary']);

        // add the menu to the editor
        editor.ui.addRichCombo('strinsert', {
            label: 'Insert Content',
            title: 'Insert Content',
            voiceLabel: 'Insert Content',
            className: 'cke_format',
            multiSelect: false,
            panel:
                {
                    css: [editor.config.contentsCss, CKEDITOR.skin.getPath('editor')],
                    voiceLabel: editor.lang.panelVoiceLabel
                },

            init: function () {
                this.startGroup("Insert Content");
                for (var i in strings) {
                    this.add(strings[i][0], strings[i][1], strings[i][2]);
                }
            },

            onClick: function (value) {
                editor.focus();
                editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
                editor.insertHtml(value);
                editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is how I am enabling the plugin:

```
 CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal("strinsert", "/bundles/common/js/strinsert/", "plugin.js");
```

But is not showing up and I don't see any error on the console.

First I though it was a dependency problem for the [richcombo](http://ckeditor.com/addon/richcombo) plugin so I've downloaded and enabled as well:

```
 CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal("richcombo", "/bundles/common/js/richcombo/", "plugin.js");
```

But still not working, what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE: Adding complete configuration**

In the OP I completely forgot to add the whole configuration and this may cause people not to understand where the issue is coming from, so here it's:

```
var ivory_ckeditor_templates_content = CKEDITOR.replace("templates_content", {
    "language": "en",
    "toolbar": [
        ["Source", "-", "NewPage", "Preview", "Print", "-", "Templates"],
        ["Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "PasteText", "PasteFromWord", "-", "Undo", "Redo"],
        ["Find", "Replace", "-", "SelectAll", "-", "Scayt"],
        ["Form", "Checkbox", "Radio", "TextField", "Textarea", "SelectField", "Button", "ImageButton", "HiddenField"], "\/",
        ["Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "Subscript", "Superscript", "-", "RemoveFormat"],
        ["NumberedList", "BulletedList", "-", "Outdent", "Indent", "-", "Blockquote", "CreateDiv", "-", "JustifyLeft", "JustifyCenter", "JustifyRight", "JustifyBlock", "-", "BidiLtr", "BidiRtl"],
        ["Link", "Unlink", "Anchor"], ["Image", "Flash", "Table", "HorizontalRule", "SpecialChar", "Smiley", "PageBreak", "Iframe"], "\/",
        ["Styles", "Format", "Font", "FontSize", "TextColor", "BGColor"],
        ["TextColor", "BGColor"], ["Maximize", "ShowBlocks"],
        ["About"]],
    "extraPlugins": "templates,richcombo,strinsert",
    "templates": "oneview_templates"
});

ivory_ckeditor_templates_content.on('change', function () {
    ivory_ckeditor_templates_content.updateElement();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[addExternal](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.resourceManager-method-addExternal) just tells CKEditor where the plugin resides, it doesn't load the plugin. You also need to use [extraPlugins](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.resourceManager-method-addExternal) property and also put the name of the rich combo in the [toolbar](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar) property like this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal("strinsert", "/strinsert/", "plugin.js");
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'strinsert',
    toolbar: [
        [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'strinsert' ]  // sample toolbar
    ]
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want the rich combo to appear automatically in the toolbar without specifying it manually, you have to specify the appropriate [toolbar group](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar-section-toolbar-groups-configuration) in its definition like this:

```
editor.ui.addRichCombo('strinsert', {
    toolbar: 'insert',
    // all the other properties
```

But, if you need a custom toolbar, then you also need to specify [toolbarGroups](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarGroups) property and the easiest way is throught the [toolbar configurator](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/full-all/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html) (choose Basic type, customize it and press "Get toolbar config" button). If you don't need a custom toolbar, don't specify CKEditor `toolbarGroups` and CKEditor `toolbar` properties, so CKEditor will use its default toolbar groups.

Also, according to [CKEditor docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample-section-creating-the-toolbar-button):
You can influence the position of the button in the toolbar group by providing an optional index, for example:

```
// This could position the button at the beginning of the "insert" group.
toolbar: 'insert,0'

// This could position the button at the end of the "insert" group.
toolbar: 'insert,100'
```

Note: The exact position depends on the indexes defined by other buttons available in your toolbar, so it may take some experimenting with index values to create a perfect button sequence within a group.

Comment: Should not the button being inserted in any toolbar by default? As for the extraPlugins you mention I have edited the OP showing I have those enabled